# Sitecore could not start custom MessageBus

Tags: untagged

I have a custom message bus implementation in **Sitecore 9.1.1**:

```
namespace Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus
{
    public sealed class CustomMessageBus
    {
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role">
  <sitecore>
    <Messaging role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
      <Rebus>
        <Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus.CustomMessageBus>
          <Transport>
            <SqlServer>
              <OneWay>false</OneWay>
              <ConnectionStringOrName>messaging_sync</ConnectionStringOrName>
              <TableName>Sitecore_Transport</TableName>
              <InputQueueName>CustomMessagesQueueName</InputQueueName>
            </SqlServer>
          </Transport>
          <Subscriptions>
            <SqlServer>
              <ConnectionStringOrName>messaging_sync</ConnectionStringOrName>
              <TableName>Sitecore_Subscriptions</TableName>
              <IsCentralized>true</IsCentralized>
            </SqlServer>
          </Subscriptions>
          <Logging Type="Sitecore.Messaging.SitecoreLoggerFactory, Sitecore.Messaging"/>
        </Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus.CustomMessageBus>
      </Rebus>
    </Messaging>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Registration:

```
    public class InitializeMessaging
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public InitializeMessaging(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        }

        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            _serviceProvider.StartMessageBus<CustomMessageBus>();
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"InitializeMessaging: CustomMessageBus", this);
        }
    }
```

It works fine on my **local standalone** environment, but on **production** we do not have *EXM*, *MA* and *xConnect* at all. There were no **Messaging** section in *showconfig* at all before I deploy my config.

An exception is thrown on line:

```
 _serviceProvider.StartMessageBus<CustomMessageBus>();
```

Error message:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: No bus exists for name 'Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus.CustomMessageBus'.
Parameter name: busName
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageBusRegistry.EnsureIsStarted(String busName)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.ServiceProviderExtensions.StartMessageBus[TBusName](IServiceProvider provider)
```

OK. After some investigation I found that MessageBus exists in **processing.tasks.messaging** section. And I tried to wrap my configuration in:

```
<processing.tasks.messaging />
```

In this case I catch another exception:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Rebus configuration section 'Transport' for bus 'Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus.CustomMessageBus' was not recognized.
  at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.Configuration.RebusConfigurator.ParseBusConfigSection[TConfigurator,TConfig](IConfigurationSection busConfiguration, TConfigurator[] configurators, Func`2 selectReadMethod, String sectionName, Boolean sectionRequired, Int32 minChildren, Int32 maxChildren)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.Configuration.RebusConfigurator.ConfigureTransports(IConfigurationSection busConfiguration, RebusConfigurer rebusConfigurer)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.Configuration.RebusConfigurator.Configure(IConfigurationSection busConfiguration, RebusConfigurer rebusConfigurer)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageServiceBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_3.<AddBuses>b__3(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageBusRegistry.EnsureIsStarted(String busName)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.ServiceProviderExtensions.StartMessageBus[TBusName](IServiceProvider provider)
```

Maybe someone faced with similar issue or has any suggestions how to fix it or may be I need to deploy some files from EXM/MA?

Comment: I assume it's on the production CM you're seeing this issue?  Also is the queue table (CustomMessagesQueueName) successfully getting created in the Messaging DB (wherever messaging_sync is connecting to)?

Comment: Yes, it`s on CM instance. Queue table isn`t created, because message bus even didn`t initialized. It seems that problem is that it is missing in DI service colllection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that **Sitecore Messaging** was *disabled* on production (there are no **App_Config/Sitecore/Messaging** configs at all).

Solutions:

1. Enable Sitecore Messaging (copy **Sitecore.Messaging.config**)
2. Implement and register custom **ServicesConfigurator**

```
  public class MessageBusConfigurator: IServicesConfigurator
  {
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
      serviceCollection.AddMessaging(config =>
      {
          IMessageServiceBuilder builder = config;
          Func<IConfiguration> configurationFactory func = (Func<IConfiguration>) (() => (IConfiguration) new ConfigurationBuilder().AddSitecoreXml("Messaging").Build().GetSection("Rebus"));
          builder.AddBuses(configurationFactory, (Action<RebusConfigurationServices>) (_ => {}));
      });
    }
  }
```

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type="Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus.MessageBusConfigurator, Sitecore.Foundation.MessageBus" />
        <services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```